# No output for recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, bufferedreader

I have the following method to read a file and output its lines in reverse order:

```
public void Reverse(BufferedReader br, PrintWriter pw)
{
  try
  {
    String headLine = br.readLine();

    if (headLine != null)
    {
      Reverse(br, pw);
      pw.println(br.readLine());

    }//if
    pw.println(headLine);      
  }//try
}//Reverse
```

For some reason, I am not seeing anything in the output file when the code is run It is compiling correctly though. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't say it for sure without seeing the rest.  What is your printwriter pointing to? are you flushing it at the end? Are you correctly closing your streams.  Also, I don't see why you have the extra println(br.readLine()) after your recursive call. I think it should work without it.  You also don't have a catch or finally block, but I guess that has more to do with the pasting to SO.

Comment: Well... If it's null, it prints. Then it returns to the `if` condition and tries to read a line after it's gotten a null and prints it--did you try checking for exceptions?

Comment: **Do not** call `br.readLine()` twice! That's your first problem. Just print headLine.

Comment: As others said the code won't compile and the recursion is not correct, that will print such much lines "null" as lines has the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your code won't even compile - you have a try block with no catch or finally block. When we can't see your real code, it's even harder than normal to know for sure what's going on.

Secondly, you're calling `readLine()` twice for no obvious reason, and then writing out `headLine` even if it's null. Shouldn't your code really be:

```
if (headLine != null)
{
  Reverse(br, pw);
  pw.println(headLine);
}
```

without the extra `println` afterwards?

My guess is that you're never flushing or closing the `PrintWriter`, and you've got auto-flush turned off. Don't do that. Or maybe there's an exception somewhere, which `PrintWriter` isn't going to report because it swallows them. Personally I'd recommend taking just a `Writer` or `BufferedWriter` instead of a `PrintWriter`, and declaring that `Reverse` can throw `IOException`. Then make sure that the calling code closes the writer in a finally block.

I'd also suggest *not* using recursion for this, unless you're *just* using this as a way of investigating recursion. It would be far saner to read the whole file into a list of strings, reverse it, then write it all out.

Comment: It's homework, thus recursion. You can easily spot it by the method name "Reverse" :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
public void Reverse(String headLine, BufferedReader br, PrintWriter pw) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        headLine = br.readLine();

        if (headLine != null)
        {
            Reverse(headLine, br, pw);
            pw.println(headLine);

        }//if
        //pw.println(headLine);
    }finally {
    }
}
```

here, initially send the headline as ""

Answer (score 0):

Your original code try to write a newly-read line after all lines have already been read.

What you need is to write the `headline` value after calling `Reverse` again, like this:

```
public void Reverse(BufferedReader br, PrintWriter pw) throws IOException
{
        String headLine = br.readLine();

        if (headLine != null)
        {
            Reverse(br, pw);
            pw.println(headLine);

        }
}
```